# Select distinct values from one column and sum another column

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, unique

I have this stored procedure shown here which calculates the order qty, rejection and percentage for rejection against each department, but I have an issue: for summing the order qty, I need to consider only distinct order number to sum the order qty, but for rejection qty all rows should be considered. How to achieve this?

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE orderqtyper
    @fromDate Date,
    @toDate Date
AS
    SELECT 
        Department, 
        SUM(Order_Qty) AS [Order Qty],
        SUM(Rejection_Qty) AS [Rejection Qty],
        FORMAT((SUM(Rejection_Qty) * 100.0 / NULLIF(SUM(Order_Qty), 0) / 100), 'P') AS Percentage   
    FROM 
        Semicon_NPD
    WHERE 
        (Date BETWEEN @fromDate AND @toDate)
    GROUP BY 
        Department
    ORDER BY 
        Percentage DESC
```

Sample table:

[image]

Current result:

[image]

Expected result (*if the the order number is the same, it should take sum of only unique values for order qty but sum of all for rejections qty*):

[image: Here if the the order number is same it should take sum of only unique values for order qty but all for rejections qty]

Comment: Your table is denormalized. `RejectionQty` should have been a separate table with a foreign key then you would only have a single row to deal with

Comment: Hi @Charlieface..i am new to sql server could you pls explain more..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DISTINCT` as SUM(DISTINCT <column_name>)

```
create proc orderqtyper
@fromDate Date,
@toDate Date
as
SELECT Department, 
    SUM(DISTINCT Order_Qty)as [Order Qty],
    SUM(Rejection_Qty) as [Rejection Qty],
   Format((SUM(Rejection_Qty) * 100.0 / NULLIF(SUM(Order_Qty), 0)/100),'P')  AS Percentage   
FROM Semicon_NPD
Where (Date between  @fromDate  and  @toDate)
GROUP BY Department
order by Percentage desc
go
```

Comment: Hi @Susang ..thank you for your response but i need the distinct order number and sum of order qty ...how to achieve it?

Comment: You are grouping the data department wise and each depart has a unique order number, so in such case, you won't get the expected result that you have mentioned above but you can select min/max order number or group the data by department and order number wise. Finally, the result will be different with more rows.